# Merge Date & Time field in to datetime field using formula field

Tags: formula-field, date, datetime, time

We have to separate fields to pick appointment date & appointment time in Custom object.
Now we have to filter out appointments between two dates (w/ time), so I need to compare appointment date & time both.
For that, I am thinking to create a Formula field which takes both appointment date & time & provide appointment date & time in date/time type. Please provide formula to do so

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried formula field using below,

```
DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(Appointment_Date__c) + " " + LEFT(TEXT(Appointment_Time__c), 8)) + 7/24
```

But since it will not work only for daylight saving period (GMT-7), but not for standard timezone (GMT-8). So formula field doesn't work for such timezones.

For such timezones, we have the only option of Apex, so I created trigger & it worked.

```
trigger UpdateAppointemntDateTime on Ride__c  (before insert,before update) {
    for(Object__c r : trigger.new)
    {
        if(r.Appointment_Date__c != null && r.Appointment_Time__c != null){

            String timeString =  String.valueOf(r.Appointment_Time__c);

            r.Appointment_Date_with_Time__c = DateTime.newInstance(r.Appointment_Date__c, 
                                            Time.newInstance(
                                                Integer.valueOf(timeString.split(':')[0]),
                                                Integer.valueof(timeString.split(':')[1]), 
                                            0, 0));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can handle this in Apex like this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(myDate, myTime);
```

Comment: Awesome, just what I needed- simple and clean. Thank you!

Comment: OP asked for a formula

Answer (score 1):

DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT( App_Date__c )+ " "+ TEXT( App_Time__c ))+x/24

Note: X incidate time Zone difference (Kindly check user setting to know the Time Zone that has been mapped  Name-> My Settings -> Language & Time Zone)